# useEffect called multiple times when using <Redirect> or history.push()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I got a little problem because I can't redirect logged in user to app, when he's saved in localStorage.
Both react-router-dom functions return `Maximum update depth exceeded.` but why?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { authLocalUser } from 'actions/userActions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

// components
import SigninForm from 'components/organisms/Forms/SigninForm'
import SignupForm from 'components/organisms/Forms/SignupForm'

// styles
import { Content, Footer, Wrapper, Header } from './styles'

const Landing = ({ fetchLocalStorage, userID }) => {
    const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)
    const history = useHistory()

    useEffect(async () => {
        const userData = await JSON.parse(
            localStorage.getItem('userData'),
        )
        await fetchLocalStorage(userData)
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            {userID && history.push('/app')}
            <Content>
                {isModalOpen && (
                    <div
                        style={{
                            zIndex: 300,
                            left: 0,
                            position: 'absolute',
                            width: '100%',
                            height: '100%',
                            background: 'rgb(0,0,0,0.5)',
                        }}
                    >
                        <SignupForm setModalOpen={setModalOpen} />
                    </div>
                )}
                <Wrapper w='60'>
                    <Header>
                        <h1>ChatterApp</h1>
                        <h3>
                            Chat with your friend in real-time using
                            magic of Web Sockets! Join our community
                            today!
                        </h3>
                    </Header>
                </Wrapper>
                <Wrapper signin w='40'>
                    <SigninForm setModalOpen={setModalOpen} />
                </Wrapper>
            </Content>
            <Footer>
                <Content>
                    <h3>ChatterApp</h3>
                    <h5>Dawid Szemborowski</h5>
                </Content>
            </Footer>
        </>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ user }) => ({
    userID: user._id,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchLocalStorage: localStorage =>
        dispatch(authLocalUser(localStorage)),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Landing)

Landing.propTypes = {
    userID: PropTypes.string,
    fetchLocalStorage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

Landing.defaultProps = {
    userID: undefined,
}
```

I tried calling this function without async/await, I tried providing userID and localStorage as that last parameter for componentDidUpdate. Where is my problem? Error I get displays the problem is inside Lifecycle component

```
index.js:1 The above error occurred in the <Lifecycle> component:

    at Lifecycle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:47761:29)
    at Redirect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:47862:28)
```

authLocalUser code

```
export const authLocalUser = userData => {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_LOCAL_STORAGE',
        payload: userData,
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire code?

Comment: @RohitKashyap for fetchLocalStorage or the entire Landing page?

Comment: Entire code, if possible please consider reproducing the issue on codesandbox

Comment: just edited post, rest of app is empty, only reducers and store setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this.

Replacing `{userID && history.push('/app')}` with:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(userId) {
    history.push('/app')
  }
}, [userId])
```

As a suggestion, your first `useEffect` call can be corrected. If you make the `callback` of `useEffect` as `async` it will return a promise which is not the way `useEffect` works. It returns a `cleanup function`.

Use an `IIFE` instead:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    
      (async () => {
        const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'))
        await fetchLocalStorage(userData)
      })()
    
    }, [])
```

Comment: Okay separating these two useEffects helped me, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. mark the answer as correct and upvote it, might benifit future readers.